# The integral change if we change the domain.

Tags: complex-analysis, elliptic-curves, riemann-surfaces, elliptic-integrals

Let $E$ be an elliptic curve over complex field.
To integral holomorphic differential form $ω＝dx/y$ on $E$, we cut riemann surface and glue them together to avoid multiplicity of integrand, and gain a torus.

We integrate $ω$ on torus, but I have question.

Integral on torus may be different from original path on $E($$\mathbb{C}$$)$.
For example, if we take path $α$ on $E($$\mathbb{C}$$)$ and corresponding path $α'$ on torus, there is no need of conincidence of two integral $∮ω$ on $α$ and $∮ω$ on $α'$. The integral change if we change the domain.

Nevertheless, why (or in what kind of perspective) can we calculate the integral $∮ω$ on $E$ by studying integral on torus?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "gain a torus". $E(\mathbb{C})$ is a Riemann surface, and there is a perfectly well-defined notion of integration along a path on a Riemann surface; see chapter IV of Miranda's *Algebraic Curves and Riemann Surfaces*, for instance. If you change the path $\alpha$ to a different path $\alpha'$ with the same endpoints, you will get a different value for the integral. However, the difference $\int_\alpha \omega - \int_{\alpha'} \omega$ will be an element of the period lattice $\Lambda$. This is because the concatenated path $\alpha*\alpha'$ is a closed loop.

Comment: My point is that : integral on the path α on  C∪｛∞｝　 and α' on torus is not necessarily the same. 'to gain torus' means to glue two branch cut Riemann sphere. See Silverman's 'the arithmetic of elliptic curves', introduction of chapter 6.